# ko.computed() does not evaluate for top level object (knockout mapping)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, computed-observable

I have two values on page, one is ko.computed property other ko.observable, both should get same value but in two different ways (base data is loaded using ko.mapping.fromJS):

```
        //#1
        self.count = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.pages().length;
        });

        //#2
        self.count2 = ko.observable(0);
        ko.computed(function () {
            //looks like this is not fiering
            self.count2(self.pages().length);
        });
```

In my case #1 works great, but #2 fails to trigger at all. in same manner if i would use self.page.subscribe(), i would also get desired result.

And there is second part to this problem, if i create some nested objects, then case #1 and #2 work as expected for nested ones, but problem still exists on top level / parent object.

And hear is sample that demonstrates this strange behavior - http://jsfiddle.net/rrgnK/2/

I would like to know what causes this problem, is it my code / structure or something else?
(there is no particular problem i'm trying to solve this way, i just noticed this strange behavior and that lead me to thought that i may be doing something fundamentally wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Your second `.computed` field isn't bound to anything, it'll never get called.

I don't have a proposed fix because that's simply not what you're supposed to do.  Your first code pattern is the expected way to get read access to a variable derived from some other property.

Comment: such use of ko.computed is mentioned in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

and then again, how comes that it works for child objects?

Comment: @dzjosjusuns I don't see any example there matching your code.  You've created a read-only `computed` which attempts to _write_ to `.count2` but which doesn't return a value.  This should make the former dependent on the latter, but as you don't assign the former to a property it still never gets used.

Comment: Looks like it was a bug in plugin - https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/issues/131

Comment: i submitted the pull request for that bug, but the way you are using it is not the intent.  @Alnitak this works because mapping overrides the normal ko.computed method and captures any computeds that are created then evaluates them prior to returning...even if the result isn't assigned to anything.  all this code is doing is making sure that the computed is evaluated by mapping's fromJS at some point... FYI  if you checked count2 after a setTimeout call in old code you'd see that #2 would update.

Comment: @ChrisDaMour right - I hadn't spotted that the OP was using a plugin - the only mention of it was in the tags.